# how to change default theme to custom theme for sitemap page?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have enabled sitemap on my magento website. unfortunately it was displaying in magento's default template how to enable my custom theme for the sitemap page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the theme for the default Magento sitemap via layout handler XML files.
Check if you have `catalog.xml` in your theme layout:

```
app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/layout/catalog.xml
```

If you don't, copy it over from this folder:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml
```

For changing template or package/theme of the default Magento sitemap page, edit it as following:

Find this block:

```
<catalog_seo_sitemap translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Seo Sitemap (Common)</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

Add this line of code to the `<reference name="root">` section:

```
<action method="setTheme"><theme>default/iphone</theme></action>
```

Test if it works. Now you can replace `default/iphone` with your own `package/theme`:

```
<action method="setTheme"><theme>YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME</theme></action>
```

If it does not work, try the usual:

- clear cache
- flush cache storage / delete /var/cache folder content